# Health Insurance Usage for Employers

Tags: health-insurance, employer

Do employers look at health insurance usage, and use that data to possibly lay people off for incurring too much usage?

1) Would such a practice be legal
2) Even if it were illegal, could employers be using such data regardless?

Thanks

Comment: 3) Why would an employer even care enough to do this, considering it's the insurance company (not the employer) who's paying insurance claims?

Comment: Smaller employers participate in groups, and the premium is determined by the groups' usage (I believe so).  Insurance company is not going to cover you at a loss.   You may incur large expense one year due to operation etc.

Comment: Premiums are based on risk factors, though, not actual usage. Your employer's group plan's premiums don't go up just because one of its employees had a particularly unlucky year.

Comment: And yes, if you have just about any medical condition worse than the sniffles, you're a net loss for the insurer for that year. And they have to cover it. That's one of the costs of being able to charge $hundreds/month to a captive audience of people who rarely get sick or hospitalized.

Comment: Anybody can confirm what cHoa is saying?

Comment: I think the question needs to be divided up. 1: Can health insurance companies legally set premiums based on their actual expenditures? 2: Can they report named individual "expenses" (relative contribution to group premium) to the employer? 3: Can employers terminate an employee because they contribute too much to the overall rate.

Answer (score 2):

The "[Privacy Rule](https://www.hhs.gov/sites/default/files/ocr/privacy/hipaa/administrative/combined/hipaa-simplification-201303.pdf?language=es)" of HIPAA would prohibit this from happening. §164.504(f)(2)(ii) imposes requirements on group health plan documents (agreements), which must

> Provide that the group health plan  will disclose protected health 
>   information to the plan sponsor only  upon receipt of a certification
>   by the  plan sponsor that the plan documents  have been amended to
>   incorporate  the following provisions and that the  plan sponsor
>   agrees to

...

> (C) Not use or disclose the  information for employment-related 
>   actions and decisions or in  connection with any other benefit or 
>   employee benefit plan of the plan  sponsor;

We can infer from this that the insurer could disclose to the sponsor such details (since the sponsor must agree not to use it to e.g. fire people).